# Send keystrokes to Mail app using Swift and Apple's Scripting Bridge

Tags: swift, xcode, applescript, scripting-bridge

I have a simple Swift app that needs to be able to control and send keystrokes to Mail.app. In pure AppleScript I'd do something like:

```
tell application "Mail"
  activate
  tell application "System Events" to keystroke "2" using command down
```

I've read Apple's [Scripting Bridge Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH1-DontLinkElementID_18) and [Communicating with Apps using AppleScript and Swift](https://brightdigit.com/blog/2017/06/09/scriptingbridge-with-swift-communicating-with-apps-using-applescript-and-swift/) so I'm able to do this in Swift:

```
if let application = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Mail") {
  let mailApplication = application as MailApplication
  ...
```

What I don't understand is how I can replicate AppleScript's `tell application "System Events" to keystroke ...` functionality in Swift. "System Events" isn't an SBApplication so I can't get a reference to it the same way I can Mail.app.

Comment: Scripting Bridge is outdated. Use AppleScriptObjC or NSAppleScript

Comment: What does ⟨⌘⟩+⟨2⟩ do in _Mail_ ?

Comment: @CJK You can add folders to a "favorites bar" in Mail and then quickly access them via ⌘+1, ⌘+2, etc. https://imgur.com/a/H4pDh1k

Comment: @vadian: I don’t know about outdated, but it’s certainly junk. Best approach is to call [AppleScript handlers directly from Swift via AppleScript-ObjC](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html).

Comment: where does MailApplication come from? Is there some sort of import?

Answer (score 0):

No need to emulate keystrokes using GUI Scripting, which is brittle and flaky. While not exactly obvious from Mail’s dictionary (which is a mess), you can use AppleScript to select mailboxes directly.

The trick is to manipulate the `selected messages` property of the frontmost `message viewer` object.

The `application` class defines properties containing references to the standard mailboxes (`inbox`, `outbox`, `drafts mailbox`,  etc):

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selected mailboxes of message viewer 1 to drafts mailbox
end tell
```

Or you can refer to custom mailboxes by name:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selected mailboxes of message viewer 1 to mailbox "Foo"
end tell
```

(To find out the names of custom mailboxes, use `tell application "Mail" to get name of every mailbox`.)